# SlidingUpPanelLayout problem with visibility

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I have a problem with SlidingUpPanelLayout. My view is build like that:

```xml
 <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/list_sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="@dimen/filtering_list_closed_height"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="@dimen/app_bar_elevation">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            // some views

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_filtering_fragment_container"
            android:name="com.example.test.scenes.list.filtering.FilteringFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

and it was working until I've added new feature where I have to set `list_filtering_fragment_container` visibility to `GONE`. Everything works fine when I switch visibility status but it's not working when I move to another fragment and come back to previous one.

**EDIT**

It looks like:

Normal state that I want to achieve after set visibility to `VISIBLE`

[image: BEFORE]

State that I have after set visibility to `VISIBLE` (after changing fragments)

[image]

also I can see in layout inspector that location on Screen and height of this element is different for both cases. 
I tried to use `slidingUpPanel.setPanelState(PanelState.HIDDEN)` but it for some reason doesn't work in 100% cases. It look like view goes outside screen and doesn't come back to it's proper position. And question is why it behaves like that?

Comment: your question is confusing can you really explain what you want to implement

Comment: @Mr.Patel I have problem with disappearing layout like you can see on pictures (this gray content below appbar) after chaning visibility.

Comment: That's pretty easy to fix